# Angular velocity in Euler's equations (Rigid body)

Tags: precession

I was confused at something...
Look at these equations: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_equations_(rigid_body_dynamics)

From what I understood the way we get them is by going into rotating frame of reference, what is bothering me is, if we are in the rotating system wouldn't one of these angular velocities always be zero?

How come we go in a rotating reference frame and still have rotation along exact same axis in that frame?